# Remove duplicate strings in string vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have the code, listed below, which I am trying to get to remove any duplicate football team names from a string vector. However, it is only working sometimes, it will remove duplicate names for some of the teams; but then for others there will be multiple occurrences of the same team name in the final array.

For example it would print:

```
aresnal
wigan
villa
liverpool
villa
```

Notice there are two 'villa' names, could anyone give me a suggestion?
The 'finalLeague' is the array which is storing all of the names, and is the array which needs the duplicates removing out of.

```
  for (int i = 0;i < finalLeague.size();i++)
  {       
      string temp = finalLeague[i];
      int h = i + 1;
      for (int j = i+1;j < finalLeague.size();j++)
      {
          if (finalLeague[j] == finalLeague[i])
          {               
              finalLeague.erase(finalLeague.begin()+j);     
          }     
      }
  }
```

Comment: it will be easy to check when you  add an element : if the element already exist don't add it .

Answer (score 7):

Sure, you can use a combination of `std::sort`, [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) and `std::vector::erase`:

```
std::sort(finalLeague.begin(), finalLeague.end());
auto it = std::unique(finalLeague.begin(), finalLeague.end());
finalLeague.erase(it, finalLeague.end());
```

Alternatively, use a container that does not accept duplicates in the first place:

```
std::set<std::string> finalLeague;           // BST, C++03 and C++11
std::unordered_set<std::string> finalLeague; // hash table, C++11
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use std::unique

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
// filling vector
// ....

std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;
it = std::unique (vec.begin(), vec.end());
vec.resize(std::distance(vec.begin(),it));
```

@edit: as @Gorpik said, vector must be sorted before use std::unique, otherwise only equal consecutive elements will be deleted.

Comment: `std::unique` only removes consecutive duplicates. You would need to sort the vector before using it.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using a hashmap. Using `#include <unordered_map>` will let you use it. Note that you *might* have to use `C++ 11` for it. Read about unordered maps [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/).

All you need to do is check whether the string has occurred before or not and keep pushing unique strings into a new vector.

USP of this method is that it needs minimal amount of code. Just one loop would do the trick.

Comment: It not available since c++11. It's officially standardized since c++11. It is available in many popular c++ compilers as an extension since long ago.

Comment: In gcc it was present already in 3.4 as `hash_map`. There is a [bugfix report in change log](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.4/changes.html). And this dates back to 2006. I believe that vc++ had something similar. But of course there might be differences, although my point is simply if one has and old pre-c++11 compiler, they should not get discouraged in case they need similar functionality.

Comment: `std::map` will also work. It's the `map` part that matters initially, not the implementation detail.

Comment: I guess my answer should have been just that he could also use hashmaps.